# Why is my frame stacked image showing a grid?

Tags: jpeg, noise, image-stacking

The following is an auto-equalised image of 200,000 stacked frames from a small web camera.  All the frames are of a very dark grey uniform background, and the histogram mode is about -1.5 stops below mid grey.  It's so dark in fact that the auto exposure in the web camera could not compensate for the low level.  The scene and the camera are static.  Individual frame images are very dark and full of sensor noise.  You can clearly see the stepped lens mount in front of the sensor.  The lower image is one individual frame. [I hope that it shows something as SE resamples posted images to a much lower quality, which is kinda ironic for a photography forum.]

You can also see a grid pattern over the whole image, which I take to be on the 8x8 pixel boundry of the JPEG process.  After averaging out 200,000 frames, I would have expected the image to be much much smoother, and without the apparent grid.  The mount rings yes, but not the entire grid.

If the frame stacking /smoothing process had failed or not used enough frames, I would have expected 8x8 blocks of varying colours, not just their edges.

Why is there what looks like a fine wire grid over the whole image?

[image: grided image]

[image: single frame image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**: The edge-discontinuity errors between 8×8 blocks introduced by the DCT compression used in JPEGs is magnified by your image stack, which is why the "grid" is so prominent.

> If the frame stacking /smoothing process had failed or not used enough frames, I would have expected 8x8 blocks of varying colours, not just their edges.

You appear to have a slight misunderstanding about compression used in JPEG images. You are correct that the compression in (most) JPEGs is done on blocks of 8×8 pixels. Your expectation would be true if the compression were merely as simple as just replacing each 8×8 block with the average pixel value for each block (trivially achieving 64:1 "compression" ratio).

Incidentally, this would be identical to simply downsampling your image(s) by 8 for each dimension, then "blowing up" the downsampled image by a factor 8 *without interpolation*. This would produce poor-quality images, which is why it isn't done.

JPEG compression takes advantage of the [*discrete cosine transform*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform) (DCT) of each 8×8 block. Like any *Fourier-like* transform, the DCT converts spatial information (i.e., images) (or time-domain information, such as audio) into frequency information. The DCT is favored in JPEG compression over other transforms (such as the discrete sine transform (DST), or discrete Fourier transform (DFT)) for 2 reasons:

1. The DCT coefficients (the result of performing a discrete cosine transform over data) settle quicker to near zero than other transforms; and
2. The DCT "behaves well" at the edges of the data sample. Qualitatively, this means that the DCT introduces the least edge-discontinuity between neighboring pixel blocks. However, while the edge-discontinuity is small (compared to other transforms), the *slope* of signal change at either side of a block boundary is not continuous.

Mathematically, a discrete cosine transform would result in fractional numbers that would require high-precision math to maintain accuracy. The "*discrete*" part of DCT means that the coefficients have been discretized into integer values that can be stored in a byte. This discretization is part of the absolute error between a digital image and its JPEG equivalent.

The other part of the error, and where the compression comes in, is to truncate, literally *throw away*, the high-frequency DCT coefficients. This is analogous to representing the number ⅓ in decimal: 3 tenths (0.3), plus 3 hundredths (0.03), plus 3 thousandths (0.003), *ad infinitum*. This is 0.3333... never ending. For our purposes, we say 0.333 is a decent approximation (the error is one part in 1,000, or 0.1%).

While the error is small, nevertheless it is there. Specifically, even though the DCT is better at the edges than other Fourier-like transforms, the error is most visible at the edges. **This is what you're seeing** in your composite image.

Stacking / averaging has the property of more-or-less eliminating random (stochastic) noise (i.e., non-biased sensor noise), because the noise has equal probability of being positive or negative. When you throw 200,000 fair dice, you will see that statistically, all numbers come up roughly equally. This is why you don't see magnified sensor noise in your composite image.

However, biased data, whether there by its very nature (i.e., the image of your stepped lens mount), or introduced externally, is magnified. The fact that your images were all JPEGs, meaning each frame was DCT-compressed, is *magnified* in your stack.

The reason you are seeing a pronounced grid is because the very nature of DCT compression, due to quantization error and low-pass filtering of spatial frequencies a block at a time, magnifies the slight-but-cumulative edge discontinuity errors between 8×8 blocks.

Comment: Ah.  So it's not possible to get a *wire free* image using this technique then?

Comment: @PaulUszak Not when you're stacking JPEGs. If you were stacking bitmaps or something losslessly compressed, you wouldn't have the wireframes.

Comment: And many webcams don't give you the option of anything other than jpeg, or even better quality jpeg. So yourl can improve things by: more illumination; longer exposure; better camera. For weak sources under microscopes I also use a black and white camera with a filter wheel when necessary, but you could get 50 decent webcams for that sort of money.

Comment: @ChrisH Yeh, it's an IP camera that's JPEG only.  Actually, I don't want to see the image, but work out what proportion of the binary .jpg file is due to image information, and what proportion is due to the noise /entropy.  I just don't know how to phrase the question, and what SE sub site to post it on  :-(

Comment: @PaulUszak [DSP.SE](http://dsp.stackexchange.com) sounds like it might be the perfect SE site for that question.